# Which of following statements are correct regarding supremums and infimums?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

1. A finite, non empty set always contains its supremum

Correct as in a finite set no elements are same and some element is highest

2. If $a < L , \forall a \in A$ then Sup A < L

Incorrect. Example take (1,8]. Here L= SupA =8

3. If A and B are sets with property that $a <b \forall a \in A$ and every $b\in B$, then Sup A < Inf B

Incorrect. A= (1,2) B= [2,5)

4. If sup A = s and Sup B = t then Sup (A + B) = t +s

Correct

5. If Sup A $\leq$ Sup B, then $\exists b \in B$ such that it is upper bound for A

Incorrect. A= (2,6) B =(4,6)

Are these correct ? Please and Thanks

Comment: There is a mistype in 4).

Comment: Do you consider general partially ordered sets or subsets of say, $\mathbb{R}$? Anyway, there is a mistake in your example for 2, I think.

Comment: i think subsets of R. This is question from Chapter one from Stephen Aboot Real Analysis Book

Comment: I agree with Minldack that taking $\ A = \left(1, 8\right]\ $ in item 2 doesn't demonstrate the incorrectness of the statement. because it is not true that $\ a < 8\ \forall a\in A\ $.  To obtain a counterexample to the statement you need to make the interval open at its *upper* end.  Either of the intervals $\ A = \left(1, 8\right)\ $ or $\ A = \left[1, 8\right)\ $ would do.

Comment: Apart from this, is everything fine ?

Comment: I think so, apart from one pedantic quibble about 4.  If $\ s=\infty\ $ and $\ t=-\infty\ $ (i.e. $\ B=\emptyset\ $) then $\ s+t\ $ is undefined, but $\ A+B = \emptyset\ $, so $\ \mathrm{Sup}\left(A+B\right)=-\infty $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera i dont understand your comment. how can supremum be infinity ?

Comment: @J. Deff $\ \mathrm{Sup}\left(A\right)=\infty\ $ simply means that $\ A\ $ has no upper bound ($\ \mathrm{Sup}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)=\infty\ $, for instance). It's possible that in the context from which the questions have been taken, this possibility can be ruled out, but I can't see anything in the statement of 4 given here that would enable me to do so.